# JwtSecurityToken returning wrong expiration time

Tags: c#, jwt, token

I need to check if my `JwtSecurityToken` is expired or not.

I'm using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library.

When I create a `JwtSecurityToken` like this:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: token_issuer,
    audience: token_audience,
    claims: claims,
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),                
    signingCredentials: creds
    );
```

And check its lifetime, I'm getting 2 hours **after** the current time.

I check the lifetime this way (only for test purposes):

```
var lifeTime = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(token).ValidTo;
```

And my method for validation:

```
private static bool ValidateToken(string token)
{
    try
    {
        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(token_salt),
            ValidAudience = token_audience,
            ValidIssuer = token_issuer,
            RequireExpirationTime = true
        };

        var lifeTime = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(token).ValidTo;

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(token_last, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Can anyone explain what's happening or am I doing some wrong?

---

**EDIT** (for explanation purposes)

#### Test 1

- Current time of my device: **10:06**
- Using `expiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);`
- Token's lifetime = **12:06:10** and Kind = **UTC**
- Validation is ok.

#### Test 2

- Current time of my device: **10:16**
- Using `expiration = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(5);`
- Token's lifetime = **10:16:12** and Kind = **UTC**
- Validation fails:
  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: '12/11/2017 10:16:12'  Current time: '12/11/2017 12:18:40'.`

#### Test 3

- Using `expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5);`
- Token's lifetime = **13:07:10** and Kind = **UTC**
- Validation is ok.

But **WHY** the validation passes if when I run the validation was 13:12 and token's lifetime is 13:07? Is there a minimum time to bet set in expiration?

Comment: can you explain which library is this?

Comment: @ParvSharma question edited.

Comment: kindly look at my answer

Comment: "And check its lifetime, I'm getting 2 hours after the current time." How are you checking it's lifetime, precisely? (I'd recommend using `DateTime.UtcNow` anyway, mind you...)

Comment: @JonSkeet question edited!

Comment: @ParvSharma I'll try that!

Comment: @JonSkeet Just tested ParvSharma solution again and it stopped working. I'm getting 2 hours after the current time using UtcNow.

Comment: @perozzo: My guess is that you didn't carefully look at the `Kind`, which will be UTC. Are you in a time zone which is UTC-2? If so, `DateTime.UtcNow` *will* return a value which is 2 hours later than your current local time - but with a kind of UTC, which means it's accurate. Given that an expiry should be an instant in time, it's entirely reasonable for the object to keep it in UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, here in Brazil the time zone is UTC-2 (summer). So I need to use Kind = local? Or I need to subtract 2 hours of the time I set? And why it worked last week and now stopped working?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do *anything*. I very strongly suspect that nothing is wrong *at all* other than how you're looking at the values in the debugger.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added Kind to the DateTime with UTC and it worked with my local time, but in the validation it fails because the CurrentTime is still +2 hours. So, I just used DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5) - without UTC and Kind and this things - to test if the token fails or not, and it passed the validation. I'm really not getting this...

Comment: I have no idea what you tried (you're not nearly specific enough), but I don't think you're really paying attention to what I've written. "but in the validation it fails because the CurrentTime is still +2 hours" - what is CurrentTime? You haven't shown that anywhere. How are you checking it? If you're looking at it in the debugger, are you paying attention to its Kind? Do you understand that if you're in a UTC-02 time zone, then a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of UTC for "now" *should* be 2 hours ahead of your local time? I'm afraid I can't help further while your descriptions are vague.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160929/discussion-between-perozzo-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: Given your edit, the very first thing you should do is stop swallowing exceptions blindly. Next, it's no wonder your second test is failing - you're setting the validation time to 10:16 UTC, which was two hours earlier. No-one has suggested using SpecifyKind. Both tests are behaving exactly as I expect them to - it's not clear what's confusing for you. To set the expiration correctly in UTC, just use `DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet "stop swallowing exceptions blindly" - ValidateToken will throw an exception if validation fails, so how am I suppose to handle that? Just edited the question again with another test.

Comment: @JonSkeet now at 13:15 it threw an exception for the validation. It has some minimum time for the expiration time?

Comment: Well you can start by catching the *specific* exception rather than just `Exception`, and log the exception as well, at least for diagnostic purposes. Your question at the end of the third test is still very unclear too. What do you mean by "it now seems to be 13:12"? I think you really need to take a step back and sort out any time zone confusion from anything else.

Comment: @JonSkeet Using UtcNow I get 2 hours after my current time. So let's talk in that specific time. That's is not a problem anymore. I just used what you said. So, in the third test using UtcNow I get the token lifetime = 13:07:10, but when I run the validation was 13:12 and it passed the validation. When I run the validation again about 13:15 it threw an exception. So my question is: is there a minimum expiration time to be set?

Comment: This sounds like it's now an entirely separate question, which should be *asked* separately, ideally with a [mcve]. Stack Overflow is designed to handle one question per post. The answer to *this* post's question is, "No, JwtSecurityToken isn't returning the wrong expiry time - it's returning an expiry time expressed in UTC." A question about a minimum expiration time or whether JwtSecurityToken actually allows slightly out of date tokens should be asked in a separate post.

Comment: @JonSkeet Perfect. Thank you very much for your patience, time and explanation.

Comment: Should be a DTO

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[From the only source of this library got from google search](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtPayload.cs) you can see that the time is being converted to universal time (UTC).

`DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15)` seems to be the problem.
Replacing it with `Datetime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)` might fix it

is your local time zone is UTC+2:00?

Comment: Just tested again now and it stopped working. Any ideas?

Comment: Just read the documentation you provided and it uses the following line in the code for expire time: this[JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp] = EpochTime.GetIntDate(expires.Value.ToUniversalTime()); Maybe this be the problem? "ToUniversalTime()" ?

Comment: @perozzo - hi i havent had the time to look at your comments. i will in about 5 hours when i get back to my desk

Answer (score 12):

I know, that this is an old question, but `TokenValidationParameters` class has property called `ClockSkew`, which is set by default to 5 minutes. It might be your problem, as it was mine. Just set this property to for example to 1 second - `ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong time, in fact you create the expiration time based on your local time, but it looks for Utc time. so the solution is using Utc time in serverside mthod to generate expiratoin time and then in client side check the expiration token time by UtcNow.

Server :

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(tokenValidityInMinutes),
        claims: authClaims,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );
```

Client :

```
var identity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenDTO?.Token) || tokenDTO?.Expiration < DateTime.UtcNow
```